# Processing rect statement leaving trail of other black rectangles

Tags: processing

When trying to make a rectangle come back and forth from the Frame, it leaves behind a black rectangle covering the background.

Here is my code:

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float speed = 1;

void setup() {
  size(500,500);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  move();
  display();
}

void move() {
  x = x + speed;
  if (x > width) {
    x = 0;
  }
}

void display() {
  rect(x,y,30,10);
}
```

Now I hate that since it is almost the same exact code that is in the examples.
Edit: I don't want the black color that it leaves behind. Now do some research..

Comment: So what's your question? What's the behaviour you want?

Comment: I don't want the black rectangle it leaves behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid a trailing of your triangle, you need to redraw your background before redrawing your triangle, otherwise it just draws another triangle over the top.

You should add;

```
background(255);
```

to your `draw()` method before `move()` and `display()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Processing void setup() is only Called once when the sketch is started. This is why you define the size of the canvas in it. ( as the canvas side does not change)

On the other hand void draw() is constantly running. So any active content that changes when the program is running needs to be in it.

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float speed = 1;

void setup() {
  size(500,500);

}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  move();
  display();
}

void move() {
  x = x + speed;
  if (x > width) {
    x = 0;
  }
}

void display() {
  rect(x,y,30,10);
}
```